# I need help withcombined formula

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, vlookup

Combining the following functions:

1. Write a VLOOKUP formula that will return the value based on the output (Column D)

I have: this part

2. Formula
   2: Write a formula (using the OR Function), which states, if Column D = "Blue" OR Column E >=4 then "Yes", otherwise "No"

So I have:

1. =VLOOKUP("Red",$A3:$D6,2,FALSE)
2. =IF(OR(D3="Blue",E3>=4),"yes","no")
3. ?

Comment: You should show the data provided with your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table, I am unsure of what it is exactly you are trying to accomplish as there are more than one way to combine these equations. If I guessed right, the VLOOKUP is what returns a numeric value into the E column. Then the If statement looks for the color blue or a value larger than 4 from the VLOOKUP. If this is the case, try this

```
=IF(OR(VLOOKUP("Red",$A2:$D5,2,FALSE)>=4,D3="Blue"),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: I don't know what I am trying to get from the problem. How can I put up the table on this forum?

Comment: I don't think you can at this point. You can do a make shift csv format separating the columns with commas. `1,red,2,blue` `4,blue,7,yellow`. What I did above I think is what your looking for. If the value in column A is red then it evaluates the number in column 2. If that value is greater or equal to 4 OR if D3 is Blue then it returns yes, else it returns no.